# jquery validation with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I have 3 separate forms on my web page (all forms have a unique input fields)

```
 <form id="moneyForm">
 <form id="profile">
 <form id="get_ahelp">
```

And for every form I create a validation rules like this:

```
$("#moneyForm").validate({  
    rules: {
        u_money:{required:true}             
    },          
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

var validator = $("#profile").validate({
        errorElement: "span",
    rules: {
        u_surname:{
            required:true,
            letters:true
            }                       
    },          
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

$("#get_ahelp").validate({
    rules: {
        h_name:{required:true}
    },          
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }   
});
```

When I submit 1-st form - all is ok, 3-rd it's validates normaly too.

But when I try submit second form(profile) it's somehow try to validate third form. At the same time an near an empty field of the third form, an error is generated in the **span** container]. How is this possible? Is it possible fix it and by what can be caused an error like that?

P.S. I apologize for the English, I used a translator

Comment: Assuming nothing of value was lost in the translation, is `#get_ahelp` nested into `#profile`?

Comment: Make sure you have all the necessary `</form>` tags.

Comment: Yes, there are </form> for every form.

Comment: run the page through w3c validator... improper nesting or broken tags sure seems like plausible problem

Comment: Realy one unclosed <div> caused this problem...and three hours of killed time.